# How to use range sort in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

in firebase
I want to sort the value of a certain field in descending order for a certain period of time and bring the data. I want to know how.

```
const currentTime = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now();

const twentyFourHoursAgo = new firebase.firestore.Timestamp(currentTime.seconds - (24 * 60 * 60), currentTime.nanoseconds);

//   db.collection('product').where('Timestamp', '>', twentyFourHoursAgo).orderBy('Timestamp').orderBy('participantCount', 'desc').startAfter(lastVisibleDoc).limit(3).get().then((결과) => {}
```

I've tried this now, but it doesn't seem to work.

No error, but no data coming in

Comment: When you execute that query, check the console for a logged message containing a link to configure the required Firestore index for `Timestamp asc, participantCount desc`. Additionally, you can use `const twentyFourHoursAgo = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))`.

Comment: db.collection('product').where('Timestamp', '>', twentyFourHoursAgo).orderBy('Timestamp').orderBy('participantCount', 'desc').get().then((결과) => {}
Not OK. Filtering on timestamp seems to work, but
Descending sorting by count is not possible.

db.collection('product').where('Timestamp', '>', twentyFourHoursAgo).orderBy('Timestamp').get().then((결과) => {}
it’s OK

db.collection('product').orderBy('participantCount', 'desc').get().then((결과) => {}
it’s OK